# HTML/CSS Is there a better way to center the video below the text?

Tags: html, css

I am a total newbie with HTML/CSS and stackoverflow in general so please excuse any error.

My goal: I already have a working video background in my HTML web design. Now I have figured out how to put a second video over the background.

When I insert the video, it is not centered under the 'Welcome to the Sea' tag and I'm not sure the best way to center it. I attempted to use a dl list with indentions but that doesn't appear to be the right method

could anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> Video Background </title>

</head>

    <body>
    <div class="section">
        <dl>
        <dt><h1> Welcome To The Sea </h1></dt>
            <dl>
            <dl>
            <dl>
            <dd><video controls>
                <source src="TLM2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video></dd>
            </dl>
            </dl>
            </dl>
        </d1>
    </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="color-overlay"> <div>
            <video id="video "autoplay loop muted width="100%">
                <source src="TLM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

    </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

[image: As you can see in the image it's slightly off from the text above]

This is my CSS:

```
.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1; 
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: use dev tools, right click the video and inspect element, it will highlight fairly quickly that you might have some odd margin/padding, if not easily found can you add the css to the question, you dont need the `<dl>`'s is just polluting the dom

Comment: Something you can use to center elements is a container with a flex display along with the align-items and justify-content attributes

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes! I added the CSS to the question! and I will remove the dl!

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of assistance to your problem.

```
.section video{
     margin-left: 4%;
     margin-right: 4%;
 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sqh7wuc/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed each number to 4% but it did the trick!

Comment: Wow! That actually solved one of my issues! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user12191253, you may wish to mark Universal Omega's response as the correct answer, which will reward them for their help.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the code which I commented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> Video Background </title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .section {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 1;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="section">
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <h1> Welcome To The Sea </h1>
            </dt>
            <dl>
                <dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dd><video controls>
                                <source src="TLM2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            </video></dd>
                    </dl>
                </dl>
            </dl>
            </d1>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="color-overlay">
            <div>
                <video id="video " autoplay loop muted width="100%">
                    <source src="TLM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>

        </div> -->

</body>



</html>
```